# SuperCache for Custom Templates

Tags: page-template, cache, optimization, plugin-wp-supercache

I've started creating custom templates. For instance, I wanted a news template for posts that are news oriented. So, I made news.php

```
<?php 
/*
 * Template Name: News Article
 * Template Post Type: post, page
 * Description: News Articles Template
 */
get_header(); ?>
```

And then changed the s around a bit, customized a few things, etc. A few weeks later I noticed the page load times were really slow. The number of requests jumped from 60 to 150+, Pingdom Speed Test says I need to

```
Combine external JavaScript
Minimize redirects
Minimize request size
Combine external CSS
```

But, none of this is happening on the default post template. I'm using WPSuperCache, am I correct in assuming that it isn't caching this template for some reason? Or is there some code I wrote that must be causing it not to work?